# Any intuitive explanation for Object.getPrototypeOf(Function)===Function.prototype in JavaScrip?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

In JavaScript, I have been framing the prototypical-inheritance-based constructor pattern as follows:

> if an object `obj` is an instance of a "class/constructor" `Constructor`, then `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Constructor.prototype`.

Notice that instances must (at least intuitively) come after constructors. After all, instances are produced using the constructors.

This perspective works almost all the time, but not for `Function`, because it is both a constructor, and an instance as well (with `Function instanceof Function` evaluating to `true`).

Now this apparently conflicts with my previous understanding, because it raises a chicken-or-egg problem: to create the instance `Function`, we must create the constructor `Function` first; but if we already had the constructor, we will would have the instance already because they are the same object!

(P.S. I know that we can just memorize it, but I am looking for a more intutive explanation.)

Comment: You can observe the same loop in other OOP languages as well: objects are instances of classes, classes are instances of the metaclass (e.g. `type` in python) and the metaclass is an instance of... what? The tower must end somewhere.

Comment: @georg Instead of introducing a loop (or chicken-egg situation) , can't the infinite escalation end with a small set of fixed types? Or even with null like the prototypical inheritance chain?

Comment: This is a rather philosophical question. My guess is that these paradoxes are not avoidable. Consider: every person has a mother, which is a person... etc - you see the problem?